# Authorization through a ASP.NET Web API in Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, orchardcms

Creating an ASP.NET Web API module in Orchard CMS is simple and straightforward. The following link explains how to do it and it works just fine. http://www.sebastienros.com/web-api-makes-it-in-orchard

However, the GET requests does not work when the WebAPI is running under Orchard and you use the `[Authorize]` attribute at the same time.

```
  [Authorize]
  public IEnumerable<string> Get()
  {
    return _moduleManager.GetUsers().Select(n => n.UserName);
  }
```

When I call this from the client

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");            
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:30321/OrchardLocal/api/MyWebAPIModule/Users");
Console.WriteLine(response);
```

the `response` variable returns to me the "Not found" HTML page from Orchard. Without the `[Authorize]`, it returns a list of users.

Does Orchard have something already built-in to match the credentials with a registered user in Orchard? Or is there steps missing in the process?

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx) may be a helpful resource for a deeper understand ASP.NET's Authorize attribute. It might help to look in the web.config file to see what the authentication mode is set to.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that if you are making a call in code, you need to pass any cookies in the request.

A user is authenticated against the website by the use of the aspnetAuth (or FedAuth) cookie, which is provided by the browser. So if you called /OrchardLocal/api/MyWebAPIModule/Users from the browser you would expect this to work (you should see this happen in fiddler by looking at the headers/cookies).

However if you make a call in code you need to pass cookies/auth. header yourself. The call you have does not have any of this, thus it fails (you should see the absence of the cookie in fiddler for this request).

I'm not sure why you would call the api in this way from within your own module. Presumably the API controller calls a service that does the actual workload. You could call this service directly from your Driver/Action, still safe in the knowledge that your business logic is behind the service interface.

Comment: well he would call it that way because that's what APIs are for (to expose data to the outside world) and he is probably calling an API whose services exist in another project/solution which he probably doesn't want to reference

Comment: yes, and he is asking why it doesn't work when authorize is on. It doesn't because he would need to provide the cookie if he has that attribute. I don't think Orchards authentication accepts basic username/password network credential. A better approach might be to put a custom action filter on the api and use an api key header.

Comment: I was talking about your last sentence otherwise you are right.